# OpenJPA parsing the query error after months in production

Tags: jpa, ejb, websphere, openjpa

After years of using this query, months since last redeployment, one server in our WebSphere cluster started to fail here and we can't figure out what's wrong.

WebSphere 8.5.5.10, last patch installed more than a year ago.

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1737410 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: An error occurred while parsing the query filter "SELECT c FROM BatchProcessingPeriodBean c WHERE c.workstationId = ?1 and c.processingTxnId = ?2 and c.periodState = ?3". Error message: The name "BatchProcessingPeriodBean" is not a recognized entity or identifier. Known entity names: []
at com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.mapCSIException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:167)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.mapCSITransactionRolledBackException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:618)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSDeployedSupport.mapCSITransactionRolledBackException(EJSDeployedSupport.java:700)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvokeRolledbackException(EJSContainer.java:4886)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4572)
```

**UPDATE**

persistence.xml (src/main/resources/META-INF)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JDBC_TX">
        <jta-data-source>java:/JDBC_DATASOURCE</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.server.business.period.model.ejb.BatchProcessingPeriodBean</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryName" value="JDBC_DATASOURCE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed"/>
            <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

JAR file is built using maven and sits in the root of EAR file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>components-accounting</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.30</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>BatchProcessingCounters</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <name>BatchProcessingCounters</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                    <clientExcludes>
                        <clientExclude>META-INF/**xmi</clientExclude>
                        <clientExclude>META-INF/**xml</clientExclude>
                    </clientExcludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ejb</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Entity code:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(BatchProcessingPeriodPK.class)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name="BATCHPROCESSING_PERIOD")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="FIND_BY_TXNPERIODSTATE",
    query="SELECT c FROM BatchProcessingPeriodBean c WHERE c.workstationId = ?1 and c.processingTxnId = ?2 and c.periodState = ?3"),
    @NamedQuery(name="FIND_BY_TXNSPERIODSTATE",
    query="SELECT c FROM BatchProcessingPeriodBean c WHERE c.workstationId = ?1 and c.periodState = ?2")
})
public class BatchProcessingPeriodBean extends BatchProcessingPeriod {

    public static final transient String FIND_BY_TXNPERIODSTATE = "FIND_BY_TXNPERIODSTATE";
    public static final transient String FIND_BY_TXNSPERIODSTATE = "FIND_BY_TXNSPERIODSTATE";

    @Override
    @Id
    @Column(name="PERIODID", nullable= false, updatable=false)
    public String getPeriodId() {
        return super.getPeriodId();
    }

    // ... more columns truncated
}
```

Using the query

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Resource(name = "jdbc/jconnect", type = DataSource.class)
public class ProcessingPeriodBean implements ProcessingPeriodService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JDBC_TX")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
    public BatchProcessingPeriod fetchOpenPeriod(String workstationId) {
        Query q = entityManager.createNamedQuery(BatchProcessingPeriodBean.FIND_BY_TXNSPERIODSTATE);
        q.setParameter(1, workstationId);
        q.setParameter(2, BatchPeriodState.OPEN);
        List<BatchProcessingPeriodBean> list = q.getResultList();
        // .. iterating, business logic
    }
}
```

Comment: right, and without providing `persistence.xml` (which defines entities), and where you have packaged the entities how do you expect a comment?

Comment: @BillyFrost sorry, included now, kind of didn't expect the artifact to be wrong as the rest of the cluster runs just find and this issue started only on one of them out of nowhere. The app was deployed months ago and also this affected server worked fine until now

Comment: could you show us the `BatchProcessingPeriodBean`source code and the code that creates and submits the query?

Comment: @titou10 included, thanks for help

Comment: Curious that you have a single Hibernate persistence property: <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/> 
Things like this make me question how your application is packaged. Do you have Hibernate bundles in your application? Yes, the property is ignored when your running with OJ, but it makes me wonder... Is there any reason Hibernate is trying to be used there?

Comment: hi @WillDazey, we are using Hibernate only for dev puproses (JBoss). This error occurrs on WebSphere - OpenJPA

Comment: btw., the error now has been resolved by redeploying the application. wondering what can I do to make sure it doesn't happen again

Comment: and the issue is back :-) seems like it happens when the system gets under heavy load. app server restart fixes the problem